# AWS - AMI with different config - possibilities?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create an AWS AMI with t2.micro - CentOS 7 with my custom app and other configs

Create an AMI out of it and then launch with "r4.2xlarge" or "r4.xlarge",

is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Instance type used for creating the AMI is not imposed when Creating new Instances using the Image. But

> If you customized your instance with instance store volumes or EBS
>   volumes in addition to the root device volume, the new AMI contains
>   block device mapping information for those volumes. When you launch an
>   instance from this new AMI, the instance automatically launches with
>   those additional volumes.

Comment: Note that this requires that the original and new instance types support the same type of virtualization -- HVM or PV.  Both the t2 and the r4 are HVM, so this case will work.  Most newer instance classes support HVM, most older ones support PV, and a few (hs1 and hi1 come to mind at the moment) support both.